# NavigationView handle menu item click

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

How to handle menu item clicks on NavigationView in Main Activity?

```
NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
```

I am using "Navigation Drawer Activity" template from latest Android Studio (2021.2.1 Patch 2) as a start.

Thanks.

Comment: If you are using the template from the latest Android Studio, isn't it already handling menu item clicks for you? Are you asking how exactly that works?

Comment: @ianhanniballake Exactly, it already handles but I am looking for workaround to my previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73342261 If somehow I receive clicks to menu items in Main Activity problem may be solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did hope this helps:

```
DrawerLayout drawerLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
    view.findViewById(R.id.imageMenu).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
    });
```

And then it will call this function when drawer button is clicked to open the drawer

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.miItem1){


    }
    if (id == R.id.miItem2){
        FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.ProfileFragment, fragment);
        transaction.commit();
        //startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), PopFragment.class));

    }
    if (id == R.id.miItem3){
        profileOrCoverPhoto = "image";
        showImagePicDialog();
    }
    if (id == R.id.miItem4){
        showNamephoneupdate("name");
    }
    if (id == R.id.miItem5){
        showPasswordChangeDailog();
    }
    if (id == R.id.miItem7){
        firebaseAuth.signOut();
        startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), SplashScreen.class));
        getActivity().finish();

    }
    if (id == R.id.miItem8){
        showdeleteaccountdialog();
        

    }

    return true;
}
```